# Problem about the bones

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The player has $5$ tetrahedral dice. In how many ways he can throw exactly two $1$'s and one $3$ on them, if the bones numbered?

How can I calculate this number? So far, no ideas

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{5}{2,1,2}=\frac{5!}{2!\cdot1!\cdot2!}=30$ ways to select the two dies that roll $1$, the dice that rolls $3$ and the two dies that roll something else.

After this there are $2^2$ ways to determine the outcomes of the dies that are not $1$ or $3$.

Hence the answer is $30\cdot2^2=120$